# Рекурсивная генерация перестановок

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия, список

Задача:

Дадим рекурсивное определения списка перестановок.

1. Если множество пустое, то вернем множество, 
   состоящее из пустого множества.
2. Иначе получим список перестановок от 
   множества без первого элемента и для 
   каждой такой перестановки «поставим» 
   первый элемент во все возможные места!

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
n= int(input())
def f1(arr):
    q = arr[0]
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr[0]
    else:
        arr = arr[1:]
        for elem in arr:
            print(arr.insert(elem, q))
    return f1(arr)
arr = [i+1 for i in range(n)]
print(f1(arr))
```

Только проблема в том, что возвращает бесконечное `None`, а должно возвращать все перестановки.

В чем я ошибся?

Comment: Хотя бы потому что у вас тут все перепутано.

Comment: `Только проблема в том, что возвращает бесконечное None` - метод `insert`изменяет список  и возвращает None, поэтому поэтому `print(arr.insert(elem, q))` выдает кучу `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
n= int(input())
def permutation(s):
   if len(s) == 1:
     return [s]

   perm_list = [] # resulting list
   for a in s:
     remaining_elements = [x for x in s if x != a]
     z = permutation(remaining_elements) # permutations of sublist

     for t in z:
       perm_list.append([a] + t)

   return perm_list

arr = [i+1 for i in range(n)]

for line in permutation(arr):
    print(line)
```